# HUGE XCODE BUG! Replaces lines with "utf-8;134217984"

Tags: xcode, utf-8, error-handling

Xcode started a to do very strange thing, which totally messing up my code. I can't build because I'm getting countless errors (everything worked about a week ago) and all this happening, because Xcode started to replace my lines! with the text "utf-8;134217984". This actually deletes the actual line, even if Its code!!!!
Messing up the whole project, all imports, HELP PLEASE! This happens at every start and very-very annoying.
Screenshoot:
[Image](http://i58.tinypic.com/vgjwk4.png)

Comment: First get the last working version from your version control system. Then try en create some way of repeating the bug. If you have this report it to Apple.

Comment: I can't because I saved the project on an NTFS partition which does not support version history :/.

Comment: Well then there is your problem, first you should use some kind of version control system. Git work perfectly for local projects. Then second the issue might actually be with the NTFS driver you are using to write to the NTFS drive. I don't think, actually I'm sure, it has anything to Xcode.

Comment: Was able to solve the problem, by rewriting the damaged files. I've moved all my projects to a Mac partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete and create again the file ? You problem is a bit curious could you be a bit more descriptive ?

Regards,